# Phonegap Filetransfer Upload image to Webservice

Tags: cordova, upload

I need to upload an image to a webservice using phonegaps Camera and File Transfer API.

So for example, on the Webservice have :

```
[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
        public string SaveImage(string imageData, string filename)
        {

            string success = "Nothing";

            try
            {
                string filename = "text.png";
                if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/devimg")))
                {
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/devimg/"));
                }

                string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/devimg/").ToString();

                byte[] imgByte = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);

                using (var imgStream = new MemoryStream(imgByte, true))
                {
                    Bitmap img = new Bitmap(imgStream);

                    Image i = (Image)img;
                    i.Save(path + "" + filename, ImageFormat.Png);
                    success = "Image created!!";

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                success = e.ToString();
            }

            return success;
        }
```

and in the app have:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture( function( imgdata ){
    //Base 64 encoded image file or whatever
}, CameraError , {
    quality: 50,
    destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    encodingType: navigator.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: true
});
```

The current webservice i have allows for a Base 64 encoded image to be passed into it which will then create the image and save it using the given file name. But it doesnt work if i try to access the webservice from the phonegap app.

Ive tried to access the webservice through ajax but just kept getting a bunch of error. is there a better way to upload the image to the server?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15502344/upload-the-image-to-the-remote-server-with-phonegap-ajax-and-web-service-net/15503354#15503354

Comment: Managed to fix the Http_Status 500 by adding <add name="HttpGet"/>  <add name="HttpPost"/> to my web Config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i cannot choose a comment as an answer, here is what my code looks like for future reference:
**Phonegap JS:**

```
navigator.camera.getPicture( function( imgdata ){
 var urlimg = "http:// *URL ADDRESS* /mobile.asmx/SaveImage";

 var params = new Object();
 params.otherinfo = "Whaterver"
 var options = new FileUploadOptions();
 options.fileKey = "file";
 options.fileName = imgdata.substr(imgdata.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
 options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
 options.params = params;
 options.chunkedMode = false;

var ft = new FileTransfer();
 setTimeout(function() {
  ft.upload(imgdata, urlimg, function(){
   alert("Success")
  }, function(err){
  alert("Error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
  }, options );
 }, 600);

}, function(err){
 alert(err);
} , {
 quality: 50,
 destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
 sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
 encodingType: navigator.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
 saveToPhotoAlbum: true
});
```

**WebService**

```
[WebMethod]     
public void SaveImage()
{
 if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/devimg"))){
  System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/devimg/"));
 }

string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/devimg/").ToString();

var Request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
if (Request.Files.Count > 0){
 var file = Request.Files[0];
 file.SaveAs( path + file.FileName);
 }
}
```

Comment: Single file upload functionality work fine but multiple file upload in a same url, how to do ?

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/index.html). for more information on setting parameters of file and making a call to your Web Service.