# Apache Cordova failed to load resource: The server responded with a status of 415 while uploading image to WCF service from iOS

Tags: ios, wcf, cordova, visual-studio-cordova, ngcordova

I am trying to upload an image from my iOS mobile app to a WCF service which is hosted on local IIS. I am getting this error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415
>   (Cannot process the message because the content type
>   'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryPUTlLsy2dLriRyDm'
>   was not the expected type 'multipart/related;
>   type="application/xop+xml"'.) OCRService.svc (0,0)

I couldn't find out how to fix this. Any ideas?

**Here is my Apache Cordova JavaScript:**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'ngImgCrop', 'ngFileUpload'])

    .controller("ExampleController", ['$scope', '$cordovaCamera', 'Upload', '$timeout', function ($scope, $cordovaCamera, Upload, $timeout) {

        $scope.takePhoto = function () {
            var options = {
                quality: 100,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                allowEdit: true,
                encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                targetWidth: 300,
                targetHeight: 300,
                popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
                saveToPhotoAlbum: true
            };
            $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
                $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
            }, function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                alert(err);
            });
        }    
        $scope.choosePhoto = function () {
            var options = {
                quality: 100,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
                allowEdit: true,
                encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                targetWidth: 300,
                targetHeight: 300,
                popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
                saveToPhotoAlbum: false
            };

            $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
                $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
                $scope.myImage = $scope.imgURI;
            }, function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                alert(err);
            });
        }
       $scope.myCroppedImage = '';
       $scope.upload = function (dataUrl) {
           Upload.upload({
                url: 'http://192.168.1.20/wcf/OCRService.svc',
                file: "data:image/jpeg;base64," + dataUrl

            }).then(function (response) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    $scope.result = response.data;
                    console.log(response.data);
                    alert(response.data);
                });
            }, function (response) {
                if (response.status > 0) $scope.errorMsg = response.status
                    + ': ' + response.data;
                alert(response.status);
            });
       }
   }]);
```

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-light">
        <h1 class="title">LoTTo</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content ng-controller="ExampleController" padding="true">
        <button class="button button-full button-balanced icon-right ion-ios-camera" ng-click="takePhoto()">
            Resim Çek
        </button>

        <button class="button button-full button-balanced icon-right ion-images" ng-click="choosePhoto()">
            Resim Seç
        </button>
        <center>
            <div class="cropArea">
                <img-crop image="myImage" result-image="myCroppedImage" chargement="'Loading'"
                          area-type="rectangle"
                          area-min-size="50"
                          result-image-format="image/jpeg"
                          result-image-quality="1"
                          result-image-size="{w:300, h:50}"></img-crop>

            </div>
            <div ng-show="myImage !== undefined">Gönderilecek Resim:</div>
            <div><img ng-src="{{myCroppedImage}}" ng-show="myImage !== undefined" id="image" /></div>

        </center>
        <button class="button button-full button-balanced icon-right ion-images" ng-click="upload(myCroppedImage)" ng-if="myImage !== undefined">
            Resim Yükle
        </button>

    </ion-content>
</body>
```

**Here is my WCF Service Contract related part:**

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "OCRImage?stream={stream}")]
        string OCRImage(Stream stream);
```

**Here is my WCF class related part:**

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class LoTToOCR : IOCRService
```

**Here is my WCF web config related part:**

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <!-- pick whichever binding you want .... -->
            <basicHttpBinding>

                <binding name="OCRServiceSoap"
                    closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                    maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Mtom">

                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                </binding>

            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="basic" name="LoTToOCRService.LoTToOCR">
                <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="OCRServiceSoap"
                    contract="LoTToOCRService.IOCRService" />
            <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <!--<add baseAddress=
                  "http://192.168.199.1/wcf/OCRService.svc"/>-->
            <add baseAddress=
                  "http://192.168.1.20/wcf/OCRService.svc"/>
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
```

Comment: I think it is due to CORS, still trying to solve.

Comment: have you found a solution for this issue yet?

Comment: @RGdent I will try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708797/phonegap-filetransfer-upload-image-to-webservice)